# Trying to publish a UGC Post as organisation return (403 - Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/author])

Tags: node.js, linkedin-api

Basically I'm trying to post as organisation using the token of the administrator user but I got 403 error:

```
data: {
       serviceErrorCode: 100,
       message: 'Field Value validation failed in REQUEST_BODY: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/author]',
       status: 403
}
```

Here is the request

```
{
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ organisationAdminToken,
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'x-li-format': 'json',
        'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0'
      },
      data: {
        author: 'urn:li:organisation:xxxxxxxx',
        lifecycleState: 'PUBLISHED',
        specificContent: { 'com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent': {
                                                            'com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent': {
                                                                shareCommentary: { text: 'Testing Linkedin Page Publishing' },
                                                             },
        visibility: { 'com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility': 'PUBLIC' }
      }
    }
```

Here is the result of the token inspection for the admin token:

```
 {
  active: true,
  client_id: 'xxxxx',
  authorized_at: 1653396511,
  created_at: 1653396511,
  status: 'active',
  expires_at: 1658580512,
  scope: 'r_basicprofile,r_emailaddress,r_member_social,r_organization_social,rw_organization_admin,w_member_social,w_organization_social',
  auth_type: '3L'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! The problem is here

```
    author: 'urn:li:organisation:xxxxxxxx',
```

It should be organi**z**ation not organi**s**ation :)